# Как получать html документы из другого приложения?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

Во многих программах есть кнопка "Share", которая открывает список приложений, умеющих обрабатывать этот тип файлов, например:

[image: Share file]

Я хочу, чтобы мое приложение могло обрабатывать html файлы.
Например пользователь нажимает кнопку "Share" в Google Chrome или в DropBox, а ссылка передается моему приложению.
Где искать информацию?

Comment: начните отсюда https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сначала в Info.plist прописываете:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>HTML</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.html</string>
            <string>public.xhtml</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

В AppDelegate:

```
//Swift
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    //do something with html file here
    return true
}

//Objective-C
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
    //do something with html file here
    return YES;
}
```

И передавайте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Чтобы получить url из Safari создайте App Extension:

```
File -> New -> Target -> Share Extension
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соглашаетесь создать схему, запускаете и видите:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Схема как это работает:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее в [Документации](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html)

Далее необходимо настроить. Для начала в

```
- (BOOL)isContentValid {
    // Do validation of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments here
    return YES;
}
```

Проверяете что Вам необходимо и если подходит, `return YES;` если что-то не то return `NO;`.

Включить и настроить App Groups:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И сохранять данные можно через NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *shared = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.test.one"];
[shared setObject:object forKey:@"yourkey"];
[shared synchronize];
```

Получить:

```
NSUserDefaults *shared = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.test.one"];
id value = [shared valueForKey:@"yourkey"];
NSLog(@"%@",value);
```

Comment: Попробовал сделать так как вы описали - все работает в DropBox и в файловых менеджерах. Но не работает для Safari и Google Chrome (мое приложение не отображается в списке для импорта). При этом, в Safari и Google Chrome отображается куча других приложений. Возможно как то можно указать что импортируется именно url? Не знаете куда смотреть?

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли.